# Set location Permission for custom app in MobiControl for an android classic device: Samsung A12

Tags: samsung, soti, mobicontrol

We have a custom in-house app. We use SOTI - Mobicontrol for deployment and enrolment. After a package is deployed to Android classic device, in our case it is Samsung A12, the device prompts for location permission.

We are using MobiControl 15.2 version (It is on Premise). The following script doesn't update the permission. Looks like this is only possible for Android Enterprise devices.

```
afw_set_permission_grant_state APPNAME android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION allow.
```

I have tried `afw_set_permission_grant_state APPNAME android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION allow.`. This one logs in device log

> Script command is not supported by device (afw_set_permission_grant_state)